# Receiving just the email value from a header

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm parsing email headers and need to use some values from them.

This would be a piece of the code I'm using, in this case for the last received email:

```
result, data = mail.fetch(mails_list[-1], "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
contenido = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
print (contenido['From'])
```

I'm getting the values as follows:

```
Google <no-reply@accounts.google.com>
=?UTF-8?Q?ihniwid_ingenier=C3=ADa?= <whatever@gmail.com>
```

I don't know how to receive them just as values, the email in this case, without the previous "name" and the "<>" wrapping it.

And regarding the "=?UTF-8?Q?" symbols on the second line, I have no idea why it is happening, but it does with every non-english letter, like "í", in that case. I've been searching about the text format and I checked that I have UTF-8 set in every aspect I know, windows config, environment variables...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `=?UTF-8` business is correct; [RFC 2047](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047) dictates encoding of non-ASCII characters. You can [decode them with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html)

Comment: Apply a regular expression that extracts what's between the '<' and '>'.  If you didn't want to use a regular expression, you could do it by simply finding each of those two charcters in the string independently, and then use Python's string slicing to extract the name based on those two positions (`str[p1+1:p2]`)

Comment: I've been doing that to remove the "<" and ">", working with strings, but it seemed like a "cheap" solution, because I thought there was a way to extract just the "value" part of the header, but I guess I was wrong. Thank you, anyway, guys.

Comment: Newer versions of Python have a class.headerregistry.AddressHeader class that can be used to parse (or may even be already used) this type of header.  It has an `addresses` object, which should include the addresses.  The email API is quite rich, but sometimes a bit tricky to find newer information because it has been massive extended in the last few years, and many of the examples are for older versions of Python which had much less useful parsing.